# AddPoint and shift without moving the x Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it able to append point and shift but the x axis to be static? I want  only the points to animate but not the x axis.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssbeefeater/ydhb9xrp/).

Comment: So you want new point to be added in place of your last point?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/71969mem/ - example

Comment: @stpoa i need the same animation with add point and shift  but i need the x axis to be always the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at `setData()` instead. You would provide the full new set of data points each time in that case:

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ydhb9xrp/2/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData

Comment: I need the animation that's why i need the addPoint and not the setData

Comment: Technically the axis *is* the same. You've just added another x value, and told the chart specifically to remove the first, so you're moving along the x axis. I don't see a way around this using addPoint.